# Web3js events and their callback functions are not aware of component state?

Tags: web3js

I have problem with web3js 1.2.9
Events triggering works fine and data is alright but I cannot figure out how to use component state in this functions that are triggered by event.
I cannot access state of that component where watch event is initialized.

```
this.state.contract.events.NewUserCreated()
             .on("connected",function (subscriptionId) {console.log("SubscriptionId  ",subscriptionId)})
             .on("data",function (event) {
                 console.log("Event ",event)
                 console.log("Current users")
                 console.log(this.state.users)
        
             })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function has its own `this` binding, so you cannot access `this.state` on the parent. To solve this, you can either:

1. Use an arrow function, since they don't provide their own `this` binding:

   ```js
     .on("data", (event) => {
       console.log(this.state.users);
     })
   ```
2. Bind the function to the parent's `this` object:

   ```js
   function handleData (event) {
     console.log(this.state.users);
   }

   //...
     .on("data", handleData.bind(this));
   ```

You can read more about `this` in JavaScript on the MDN docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.